# Stash authentication failed

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I recently installed and configured a Stash server.

I can login on the webinterface but then I supply the same username and password when for example doing a git clone it says :

fatal: Authentication failed for '...'

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is clone using a `ssh key`.

You can add a public ssh key in your user settings, in stash.

Then, you can clone using the ssh:// URL that will show when you're trying you clone, and you won't have to type a password ever again.

This is safer, and easier.

Comment: Yeah, but you didn't provide enough information to pinpoint the problem, so I'm suggesting a workaround :)

Comment: So I found out it's something to do with the Apache webserver in front of it. We run stash on port 7990. We have an Apache webserver that forwards incoming requests on port 80 to the ip of stash server on port 7990. This works when accessing the stash webinterface but when connecting through git command line it does not work with authenticating. (Cloning non authenticated repositories work). Authentication succeeds when changing the git clone link to ip:7990.